# Property animation performance over view animations

Tags: android, performance, animation

This is a pretty general question. Basically, I'm wondering if property animations on android have performance advantages over view animations. The documentation doesn't explicitly say that they do, but I've noticed that when I animate something with a property-based animation when it was previously a view animation, it is clearly more performant on some devices. Is it possible that the property-based animation system is able to take advantage of some hardware (or even software rendering loop efficiency) that view-based animations aren't?